# Проблема с отображением цвета SVG на сайте

Tags: css, svg

Есть svg с атрибутом fill="#ffc309", но на сайте выводится цвет #ffc30b. При изменении fill на #ffc308 - на сайте выводится #ffc30a. При изменении fill на #ffc307 - на сайте выводится #ffc308. И нужный цвет #ffc309 никак не выводится. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: воспроизводимый пример в студию =)

Comment: Вот собственно пример https://codepen.io/g1rz/pen/VwvegRV

Comment: как Вы определяете, какой в итоге цвет?

Comment: С помощью расширения ColorZilla для Chrome

Comment: посмотрел в paint - отскок еще больше, но визуально цвет тот- же, похоже на ошибки при преобразовании палитр, интересно

Comment: только что проверил color picker - цвет совпал : [снимок экрана](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhijw2is488k50x/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202020-04-16%2017.06.33.png?dl=0)

Comment: @MaximLensky а я попробовал системным.. отличается (хром)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и я пробовал системным в FF один в один - скрин приложил

Comment: Ну что ты накопал ?
я столкнулся с той же проблемой